# Show image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-feed-api

I got a litlle js code that is showing me updates from a feed

```
google.load("feeds", "1");

function initialize() {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://google.com/");
  feed.setNumEntries(1);
  var count = 1;
  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      var html = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        html = "<h5>" + count++ + ". <a href='" + entry.link + "'>" + entry.title + "</a></h5>";
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = html;
        container.appendChild(div);            
      }
      document.write(html);
    }
  });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

What i want to do is to show the first image from the posts from the feed. i would also like to have the title so entry.title and entry.content

Comment: OK, so is this a request for some code to be written for you or is there a problem that needs to be solved?

Comment: i need some code to change from showing me the title of the posts to showing me the image contained in the posts from the feed. the code works correnctly but i only get the title

Answer (score 0):

Even though parsing html with regx is big dodo, I will still advise you this,  parse your content html with `/<img\s+src\s*=\s*(["'][^"']+["']|[^>]+)>/`

Or a lazy way is to have a hidden div and do this

```
var temp = document.createElement( 'div' );
temp.innerHTML = html_str;

var images = temp.getElementsByTagName( 'img' );
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must use `entry.content` instead of `entry.title` in order to get the full HTML content of the entry. You may have something like this:

```
var content = entry.content;
var imgArray = content.match( /<img\s+src\s*=\s*(["'][^"']+["']|[^>]+)>/ );
// imgArray[0] would contain the first image (more likely the one that better describe the post)
```

P.S.: I didn't steal this Regex from actual answer, but it seems that we've got to the same [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047636/how-can-i-parse-img-src-with-a-regex#answer-4047678) for it :-)

---

UPDATE:
Then, to display it in a container, I would advise you to dynamically create DOM elements to gain more control over it, and in which you will be able to easily associate a value. Something like this:

```
var dom_h5 = document.createElement('h5');

var dom_entryTitle = document.createElement('div');
dom_entryTitle.className = 'title-classname';
dom_entryTitle.innerHTML = entry.title;
dom_h5.appendChild(dom_entryTitle);

container.appendChild(dom_h5);
```

To simplify the image part, you could create a separate div and inject the image tag as his innerHTML.

This may help you:

[Web API Reference - document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)

Comment: actually i got the idea better from your post and hi managed to get my script to work correctly, thank you so much. I know have to do some css/html work to display the image more like a slideshow. thanks again

Comment: i need some help adding the title of the post also, where and how should i add the entry.title ? i have been adding right beside the entry.content but with no sucess

Comment: If the problem lacks some information, please add it directly to the question so that we can provide complete answers. Should I remind that StackOverflow is Q&A oriented and we basically answer to specific questions. Please post all the relevant code and show what you tried so far then we'll help you from this point :-)

Comment: I edited my answer, you're not so far from a working solution, keep it up :-)